# create a chinese folder use python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I now encounter a problem about chinese charater.
I use beautifulsoup to extract data,and want to creat a folder use the name of extracted data.
data likes:

```
<A href="love">星座(1824)</A>
```

I want to extract '星座(1824)',so I do like

```
soup.find('a',href='love')
```

but in console,it come out:

```
ÐÇ×ù(1824)
```

I have use '# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-' at head of my source.
It must be some encoding problem,anyone can give some good material about python work with non-english?

I want create a folder named '星座(1824)'
I do :

```
if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
        os.mkdir('./pic/'+dir_name)
```

when I find a folder named"ÐÇ×ù(1824)' exists,so why it still come out:

```
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: './vguagua_pic/\xc3\x90\xc3\x87\xc3\x97\xc3\xb9(1824)'
```

thx

Answer (score 3):

Even if your .py script is written in UTF-8, if the webpage is not, the parsed text may not be correct.

The webpage's encoding is actually GB-2312 (or GB-18030), but BeautifulSoup guessed the webpage's encoding wrongly as ISO-8859-1, and with that incorrect assumption, converting to UTF-8 and causing mojibake. We can verify:

```
>>> b'\xc3\x90\xc3\x87\xc3\x97\xc3\xb9'.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
'星座'
```

You could add `from_encoding="gb2312"` (in bs4) or `fromEncoding="gb2312"` (in 3.x) to the BeautifulSoup constructor to force the encoding, as documented in the [Beautiful Soup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit) [(and also in Chinese 中文文档)](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.zh.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit).

Comment: >>>b'\xc3\x90\xc3\x87\xc3\x97\xc3\xb9'.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
u'\u661f\u5ea7'

Comment: >>> b'\xc3\x90\xc3\x87\xc3\x97\xc3\xb9'.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
                     u'\u661f\u5ea7'   why mine is not like your?

Comment: In beautifulsoup doc says "An encoding discovered in the document itself: for instance, in an XML declaration or (for HTML documents) an http-equiv META tag."  ,in the webpage I want to work do have a meta tag like '<META content="text/html; charset=gb2312" http-equiv=Content-Type>
',so bs should guess the right encode right?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that your console can't display Chinese characters.

I tried this on Win7, with the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
os.mkdir(u'星座(1824)')
```

the dos console shows the Chinese characters as two boxes, however, when pasting them in here they show up correctly:

```
2012-06-25  07:59    <DIR>          星座(1824)
```

they also show up correctly in Windows explorer.